# Is there a way to automatically remove all the invalid entries from an iTunes music library?

Tags: macos, itunes

I share one iTunes music directory between 2 Macs through sftp mount disk. Every time some dated podcast files are automatically removed from one computer, that change can not be reflected in the other computer's iTunes library.

Are there any AppleScripts or Automator scripts or 3rd party software on Mac OS X that could automatically remove these invalid entries from the iTunes music library?

If any script/software could also scan the music folder and auto add new entries into iTunes library, it would be even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a few great AppleScripts available at [dougscripts.com](http://dougscripts.com/). To remove invalid entries, you can use [Super Remove Dead Tracks v2.1](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/scripts01.php?page=1#removedeadsuper).

What it does:

> Surveys iTunes for tracks whose files
>   are no longer available (as indicated
>   by a "!" next to their names) and
>   removes them. Any playlists that
>   subsequently contain no tracks will
>   then be deleted. Progress is displayed
>   every 500 tracks.

To scan for new tracks, you can use [iTunes Library Sync](http://www.robertvenema.nl/wp-content/uploads/automator-itunes-library-sync-v1.1.zip) (an Automator script):

> - Place the script in /Username/Library/Workflows/Applications/Finder
>     (where Username is your username)
> - If the **workflow** directories don't exist, you have to create them
>     manually.
> - When done, the script will be available to you with a simple right
>     mouseclick (on some free desktop
>     space).
> - Select Automator -> Synchronize Library and your done.
>
> **Note:** When running this script for the first time, open Automator and
>   disable the “Date Modified” rule
>   because we want to add all the songs
>   first. When done you can enable the
>   rule again.

Both tools are freely available.

[Source](http://www.robertvenema.nl/journal/archive/itunes-library-auto-update-for-mac-os-x/)

Comment: thank you, i downloaded Super Remove Dead Tracks v2.1. it works!